# My SPF record is apparently stopping a mail relayer forwarding my message

Tags: email, spf

I have recently set up my own mail server on my VPS (CentOS, postfix and dovecot, though I don't believe any of that is relevant). I have protected it with this SPF record

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:xx.xx.xx.xx/32 -all
```

where the xx.xx.xx.xx is the IP address of my home.

This generally works, but there is one recipient to whom I have been unable to send mails. I get a bounce as follows:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; mdfmta004.tbr.inty.net
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 5016BA0C08A
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; (my email address)
Arrival-Date: Tue, 17 May 2016 13:51:34 +0100 (BST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; (destination email address)
Original-Recipient: (destination email address)
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mxa.speednames.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 "Mail from (my domain) is denied from host
    91.221.168.45 SPF"
```

It's fair enough that it's rejecting mail from 91.221.168.45, as that IP address doesn't match my SPF record. But that address resolves to mdfmta004.mxout.tbr.inty.net: it's in the same domain as the MTA that's rejecting it.

Can anybody explain to me what I must do to be able to send to this recipient?

Comment: It looks like there is some sort of forwarding happening which causes `mdfmta004.tbr.inty.net` to resend the e-mail elsewhere, at which point the SPF check fails. It will be easier to find the underlying problem if there will be more data available about recipient's e-mail infrastructure. But generally speaking, I do not think it is your fault.

Answer (score 1):

SPF is a good tool when it comes to defining who may send on behalf of your domain names. Unfortunately, there is one issue when emails are being forwarded.

Let's say, your mail server is A. You send an email to a domain, hosted on mail server B. A is listed in your SPF record as authorized sender. When the recipient on B decides to forward messages to another mail account on server C, the SPF record will be evaluated when C receives the email. Usually, the sender's address is not changed when forwarding an email. Consequently the mail server C will check, if B is authorized to send on behalf of your domain.

Basically, here is what you can do:

1) Talk to the recipient and make him aware of the problem. Instead of forwarding, setting up polling on C to look into the mailbox on B may be an option

2) If the recipient is someone you cannot ask to make changes and you need to send emails to them frequently, you can add the mail server B to your SPF record. This implies that you trust B to never abuse that constellation. This is called "trusted forwarder" in the context of SPF.

Commercial services like my company - see http://spf.guru/ - allow monitoring SPF and get an overview who is sending on your behalf.